# MongoDB learning issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Greetings I am learning mongodb and have encountered with following issue. I am pretty newbie in all of that and dived to into meanstack development after spending some hours messing with setups, I decided to spend some time learning first before doing something and found great corse of mongodb on their official website, following their lessons I cant start mongo server as it says I have already started it somewhere... :)

**Error message:**

```
2015-10-13T21:55:01.900+0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2015-10-13T21:55:01.900+0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2015-10-13T21:55:01.912+0200 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2015-10-13T21:55:01.935+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2015-10-13T21:55:01.935+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Can you please explain how can I find and remove that one or at least shut it down?

Comment: My advise is to install mongo to auto start / stop when you boot up or shutdown your machine (linux/OSX/win) ... sure its fun to learn the art of battle launching and killing it manually, however to be productive doing the legwork to automate that aspect is also essential to a good MEAN developer - good luck and welcome aboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be already a mongodb instance running. Check it with below command.

```
ps -ef | grep 'mongo'
```

You can shutdown existing mongod instance using: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-shutdown

```
mongod --shutdown
```

If no instance is running then go to the data location and remove the lock file.

```
cd /data/db/
sudo rm mongod.lock
```

Note: This is only for learning / local machine. This process might not be suitable for production.

Comment: Thank you, Lalit. Using first command I 've managed to locate it, can you please explain how to shut it down?

Comment: You can kill the process using unix kill command (only on DEV/TEST/LOCAL) or follow this: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#stop-mongod-processes

Comment: I looked throw the information you've provided for me and tried that. The message i get after typing in ps -ef | grep 'mongo' is    0 13469     1   0 Mon03PM ??         0:00.01 sudo mongod
    0 13470 13469   0 Mon03PM ??         4:04.48 mongod
  501 34396 30557   0 10:54PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep mongo

Comment: And after typing shutdown it as you provided in your post it gives a response: Error parsing command line: unknown option shutdown . Can you suggest what can be done wrong?

Comment: OK. It might be an issue with mongod version. Anyway you can directly kill the mongod process using the unix kill command. http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-kill.

Comment: It was kinda buggy, so I restared computer and it shutted down automatically, thank you a lot for the help, take care!)